# Why is Managed Service Identity greyed out in my MS Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use an MSI for a web app in Azure. I did this successfully for my first web app, but now when I have tried to reproduce in my second web app, the MSI option (and many others) are greyed out.

[image]

I cannot determine the difference between the two apps. And when I create a new app I get the same thing - many features greyed out.

I am running Azure in a dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out.

Doesn't work on Linux. Makes sense why not?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, at present, MSI only support App service on windows but does not support app service on Linux. For more details, please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-msi).